# Resize ImageView container to exactly match an image that gets placed inside of it

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` that is set to a width of `match_parent`, a height of `wrap_content` and a scaletype of `centerInside`. I then, in the code, place a horizontal rectangular bitmap inside of it and the bitmap fills the width correctly. The imageview container, however, is a square so it extends past the bounds of the bitmap in the vertical direction. How can I resize the imageview so that it exactly matches the size of the bitmap?

Comment: set adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: Doh. I knew that but I placed the property in the wrong place. I'm debating whether I should take this down or leave it in case someone else needs to know this.

Comment: make width and height to wrap_content and scale-type to fix_xy. image view will populate according to image size.

Comment: @keyur9779. But I want the image to be scaled to fit inside of the layout and keep it's aspect ratio. Will doing what you suggested still accomplish this?

Comment: @Mardymar you mean to say fit according to device width and height?

Comment: @Mardymar Just keep this question, it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `adjustViewBounds="true"` in the `ImageView` to make it fit to size of the contained image.